# Can't call std::max because minwindef.h defines "max"

Tags: c++, macros, std

How would I go about actually calling std::max? The code won't compile in visual studio 2013, because it takes "max" as the macro.

```
std::max( ... );
```

Expects an identifier after the "std::".

Comment: Have you included `cmath`? `#include <cmath>`

Comment: @user9000 `std::max` is in `<algorithm>`. The problem is a naughty VS macro.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can undefine the macro:

```
#undef max
```

**Edit**: It seems the macros can be safely disabled by putting

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

before the header files that define them (most likely `windef.h`, which you probably include indirectly).

**To avoid undefining the macro**, you can simply wrap the function in parenthesis

```
(std::max)(...)
```

As noted by chris in the comments, function-like macros require the token after the macro name to be a left parenthesis in order to expand. Wrapping the name in parentheses is really just a hack to make the next token a right parenthesis without changing the meaning once you put macros aside.

Comment: Couldn't that break things that rely on the max macro?

Comment: @Ben Probably. I found a duplicate, have a look at that. You may need some kind of guards around this. I do not use VS so don't know the effects of simply undefing.

Comment: Okay, I defined NOMINMAX. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben, You could also do `(std::max)(...)` to avoid undefining it.

Comment: @chris This is a great tip, but why does it work?

Comment: @aquirdturtle, Function-like macros require the token after the macro name to be a left parenthesis in order to expand. Wrapping the name in parentheses is really just a hack to make the next token a right parenthesis without changing the meaning once you put macros aside.